# Live preview in browser

Tags: ide, refresh, reload, visual-studio-2012

I'm looking for a tool for HTML5 + CSS3 editing. Currently the best IDE I have found is Visual Studio 2012. There is one slight problem. I want to have a live preview of what I'm creating. I have multiple monitors and it would be perfect to see the result of my code without switching to browser and hitting F5 (or Ctrl+F5). The only way I could achieve this is by using a auto-reload addon on Firefox or Chrome. But it isn't a very elegant solution. It can pretty much slow down the process because it runs so many unnecessary refreshes.

The best solution would be to somehow do this in browser (or a tool which uses browser engines) to test it in various browsers. Also it helps in situations that I'm developing server-side in PHP or ASP.NET.

Alternatively, if there is a very good IDE (better than VS) I wouldn't mind using it but please note, I'm looking for these:

- Live preview (of course)
- Intellisense
- Auto-complete features (for instance closing tags, quotations, etc.)
- Theme support (especially black) + Customization
- Zoom (not vital but I love tools which support C+Scroll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for live reload try this: [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/). It works really nice on mac, but there is a alpha version for windows too.

Comment: From what I read it's what I want. Although I have to test it. The site is down for a few hours...

Comment: I couldn't make it work on windows. I inserted the JS and used the browser extension. None worked. But it seems like the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: version for windows is pre-alpha, then can be some bugs, but mac's version works really great and I recommend it! Tomorrow I'll try on my windows, and maybe came up with solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks. It would be very appreciated. I'm looking for sth like this in Windows.

Comment: Hi. So I tried and it worked! So, I've tried on Win XP SP3 with chrome. So What I've done: download live reload installer, install it and run, add project folder (it is weird in live reload, actually nothing happend and it is empty interface but don't bother) then open your page and add script tag manually from here: [livereload.com script](http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86180-how-do-i-add-the-script-tag-manually-). And it should work! ;-)

Comment: ok. I found out that the problem was with my script tag. It will work if I add the script manually. But it won't if I use the extension of chrome (it works on Firefox). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer grunt-contrib-watch (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) as it  seems more flexible. I define in the Gruntfile.js which files shall be watched for a change and subscribe on this event any tasks I want to perform.

On the dev. environment  the project pages has reloader script that make the page refresh as soon as update event fired by grunt-contrib-watch

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

It works fine to me. Here is my grunt build script

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-jshint");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jscs');

  grunt.initConfig({
     // Lint all the files in js folder
     jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: ".jshintrc"
      },
      all: ["js/**/*.js"]
     },
     // Validate against jQuery coding standard
     jscs: {
        options: {
            "standard": "Jquery"
        },
        all: ["js"]
     },
     // Preprocess SASS
     compass: {
        dist: {
          options: {
            sassDir: 'sass',
            cssDir: 'css'
          }
        }
     },
     watch: {
        options: {
          livereload: true
        },
        css: {
            files: ['sass/**/*.sass'],
            tasks: ['compass']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['js/**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint', 'jscs']
        }
      }
  });

  grunt.registerTask("lint", ["jshint", "jscs"]);
  grunt.registerTask("default", ["watch"]);

};
```

As you run grunt you get something like that

[image]